# Bellman Ford Source & Negative Cycles

Tags: algorithms

I’m having some troubles with Bellman Ford Algorithm in the following exercise[image]

My guess is that at the end the algorithm should detect the negative cycle BD DF FG GB since B is decreasing at Vth (i.e. 7th) iteration. However changing the distance of the source does not make much sense to me. Is the source to be considered at fixed distance 0 or it can change as well as all the other vertices? Or is it correct to assume, as I did, that the algorithm will detect a negative cycle in the end?

Moreover, assuming to proceed with the computations, it is not clear to me the order I should follow. Being Vertex A not connected, should I go on relaxing from C (I guess not since it is not directly connected to B)? Or should I go on from D, which is the first vertex in alphabetic order directly connected to B?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source distance does not need to be treated specially. It can change like any other vertex. In this scenario, it'll be updated to -1 by the end of the fourth round. The weights into and out of B will never become quiescent: either B's distance will be more than 2 greater than G's distance, or (say) A's distance will be more than 5 greater than B's distance. So the cycle will still be detected.

Now, if you ever find yourself reducing the source distance below zero, you immediately know that there's a negative cost cycle, and can terminate early. But there's no need to do so for the algorithm to work.